# What do black (dark grey) files in Debian represent?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, colors, file-types

I've been racking my brain over this one for awhile now. I have scraped the web and can't find an answer anywhere.

What are black (dark grey),font  files/file-types in Linux, specifically Debian 12 bookworm. I have come across one several times now, one was a hidden .file in a directory. Is it a broken link? A corrupted file or something?

Non-graphical answers as I only use terminal. I have tried pulling up dircolors --print-database and, even there I can't find a color code for those specific files now

I'm new to this so anything will help.

Comment: show us a picture. it will really help

Comment: "black (dark grey),font files/file-types" – In the output/GUI (what?) of what program exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the description of my debian 12
[`dircolors`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/coreutils/dircolors.1.en.html)'  help and manpage, it might be the following **file access modes** for the **text** color:

```
$ dircolors -p | grep 30
# 30=black 31=red 32=green 33=yellow 34=blue 35=magenta 36=cyan 37=white
SETGID 30;43 # file that is setgid (g+s)
STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE 30;42 # dir that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
```

and/or the following **file types** for the **background** color of same text:

```
$ dircolors -p | grep 40
# 40=black 41=red 42=green 43=yellow 44=blue 45=magenta 46=cyan 47=white
FIFO 40;33 # pipe
BLK 40;33;01 # block device driver
CHR 40;33;01 # character device driver
ORPHAN 40;31;01 # symlink to nonexistent file, or non-stat'able file ...
```

So you seem to be on the right track with an ORPHANed file. If the access modes are also as described, the entry in the terminal looks almost invisible (on a black terminal background at least).

I guess the attached image remotely shows what the original author was referring to.
[image]